# how to check the custom product attribure has the particular value using loop In magento 2.4.2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes

In magento 2.4.2, I have custom attribute and it has some value assigned. how to load the product by custom attribute and how to check the custom product attribure has the particular value in for loop or in collection.

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter

```
$Collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_name', ['in' => 'value']);
```